# ListView and own row layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout where I have a listview. I have a layout for every item for this listview named: email_listview_item and this is code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/antiquewhiter">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/email_list_item_checkbox_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/form2andcheckbox_android" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_list_item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/email_list_item_checkbox_icon"
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:textColor="@color/bisque"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/email_listview_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="309dp"
        android:src="@drawable/apvpro_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to creat listview with that items but I got nullPointer. Can you help me why? 
This is code my class:

```
public class ListFragment extends ListActivity{
    ListView listView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.email_listview);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
          "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
          "Linux", "OS/2" };

        // First paramenter - Context
        // Second parameter - Layout for the row
        // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
        // Forth - the Array of data
//      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
//        R.layout.email_list_item, android.R.id.text1, values);
        Email_list_view_adapter adapter = new Email_list_view_adapter(this, values);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
    }




}
```

email_list_view_adapter:

```
public class Email_list_view_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private final Context context;
    private final String values[];

    public Email_list_view_adapter(Context context, String[] values){
        super(context, R.layout.email_list_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.email_list_item, parent,false);
        TextView desription = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.email_list_item_text);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.email_listview_image);
        desription.setText(values[position]);
        String s = values[position];
        if(s.startsWith("iPhone")){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.senddata_android);
        }else{
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.senddata_selected_android);
        }

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

This is stack trace:

```
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spot.p2a/pdf2app.ListFragment}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196):     at pdf2app.ListFragment.onCreate(ListFragment.java:30)
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
08-20 14:27:03.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9196):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Some suggestions: 1) Follow View Holder pattern 2) [Learn ListView](http://www.technotalkative.com/category/listview/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you didn't define the layout of your activity

```
 setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you assign ListView reference from your xml, you should specify setContentView() with ListView holded layout.Here it's missing that's the problem for NullPointer Exception. Better to call an method `setContentView(R.layout.my_list)` immediately next to  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Answer (score 2):

As your Activity is `ListActivity`,

First call,

```
setContentView(R.layout.listview_layout);
```

now you can just,

```
listView = getListView();
```

instead of

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.email_listview);
```

Look at this complete Tutorial on [ListView and ListActivity](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

You will get a NullPointerException on this line:

```
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.email_listview);
```

This is because you haven't assigned a layout on which to find that View, so Android looks for it in the default FrameLayout each Activity and Fragment has. You have two solutions to this:

1) Call `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file);` before you use `findViewById()`

2) Add `View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.button, null);` before that line and then change the line to `listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.email_listview);`